# origin of use of differential equations for modeling chemical reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, computational-chemistry, history-of-chemistry

what are some of the original examples of uses of differential equations for modeling and analyzing chemical reactions, particularly those relevant to biochemistry, involving proteins and enzymes? Michaelis and Menten's work in 1910s is one example.

What are the earlier examples or antecedents to this work? (references to good historical accounts of this modeling endeavor would also be helpful).

Comment: This might be better suited for History of Science/Mathematics

Comment: The inversion of sucrose by strong acids by Wilhelmy in 1850 is considered to be the first  kinetic study . Daniel Bernoulli studied the spread if disease (reported in 1766) using differential equations effectively the same as the rate equations we use today.